# True or False: If there is no money illusion, once all price elasticity is known, the income elasticity of commodity demand can be calculated

Tags: microeconomics

True, false or uncertain: If there is no money illusion, once all price elasticity is known, the income elasticity of commodity demand can be calculated.

My answer is false. I don't think it's possible to get the income elasticity from the price elasticity. But obviously my answer doesn't use the condition that "there is no money illusion".

So maybe I am wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $x_i(p,m)$ be the demand for good $i$. If there is no money illusion, this function is homogeneous of degree zero: $\forall t > 0$
$$
x_i(tp, tm) = x_i(p,m)
$$
Next use Euler's theorem for homogeneous functions. You will find that you can write the income elasticity as minus the sum of all price elasticities.

Comment: Thank you! Now I understand. Could you help me this question? https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/57790/which-of-the-two-lotteries-will-a-risk-averse-consumer-choose

Comment: I am more concerned on this question: https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/57776/which-of-these-two-lotteries-a-consumer-with-von-neumann-morgenstern-preference